# process_input_buffer callback in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, callback

I try to play with the callback function `process_input_buffer` provided by LuaTeX, but unluckily I don't get what I expect.

The manual said that

> This callback allows you to change the contents of the line input buffer just before LuaTeX actually starts looking at it.

```
function (<string> buffer)
  return <string> adjusted_buffer
end
```

> If you return `nil`, LuaTeX will pretend like your callback never happened. You can gain a small amount of processing time from that.

I try to use this callback to process my input. Firstly, I must register it

```
-- a.lua
-- the function appendSomething will append the \TeX command to end of the input lines
-- and return the adjusted string later
local function appendSomething(str)
  str = str .. " \\TeX{}"
  return str
end

callback.register("process_input_buffer", appendSomething)


% a.tex
\directlua{dofile 'a.lua'}
hello
world
\bye
```

the output is as follows

```
hello T.5exEX world T.5exEX
```

I don't get the `TeX with lower E`. Since `process_input_buffer` process the input lines before TeX actually looks at it, the `\TeX` command should be appended to the end of the input lines. After that, TeX will do the actual typesetting work and read the \TeX, converting it into a token, replacing it with its replacement texts.

But, this don't happen. Why? Why I can't get the output lines with TeX (lower E) at the end of each line?

Comment: Works here. http://i.imgur.com/ItrCPKu.png

Comment: @topskip could you tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: No, sorry. You can try to verify your input by writing `print(string.format("TeX reads: %q",str))` as the first statement of the function `appendSomething()` in your Lua file. This will output the buffer on the terminal.

Comment: what does your log file say?

Comment: @Herbert weird, it works in another file. I must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes given above can work well. I get a mistake because the careless redefinition of `\lower` in the privious part of my tex source file.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging ;-)

Comment: sometimes, I don't know I am using Rubber duck debugging :-) I found the bug by the binary search.